# Why Blender will be stalling sometimes, after finishing importing the model

Tags: python, rendering, objects

I'd like to use the python script in Blender to render my dataset.
What I do is just import models (which has a random number, and the format is '.obj'), and then doing some rendering.
But sometimes Blender will be stalling like below (not everytime, in fact most time everything is ok)
[image]

Comment: Hi, dayu dy. Are you having any issues with rendering like the project not rendering or it is just showing up but the rendering is going on as usual tor is it causing any crashes. Please comment on what problems you are facing?

Comment: You said most of the time it works, just sometimes it is stalling right? It's probably a bug. Still, try to check out your code.